# Loadning *.ini file fails in SketchUp Ruby API

Tags: ruby, sketchup

I am writting my first SketchUp plugin, and I would like to store some option in an ini file. For that purpose, I installed the IniFile Gem in SketchUp console and I have the following options.ini file in the Plugins directory:

```
[Options]
option1 = value1
option2 = value2
```

And I have the following code:

```
conf = IniFile.load( 'options.ini' )
options = conf["Options"]
```

When I run the script, for some reason the load method cannot load the ini file, and I got a runtime exception on the next line, for trying to access "Options" on a NilClass object:

```
Error: #<NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass>
```

Have somebody had the same issue before? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: How does the script know where to find the ini file? You need to supply the proper path to the ini file.

Comment: It is in the same folder as the script file. I also tried with './options.ini', but that did not work too.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to find the problem. Sketchup only stores the plugins in the plugin folder, but it calls them from the Documents folder (on Windows). As a consequence, one cannot use relative path in their scripts. Adding the following solved the problem:

```
conf = IniFile.load( File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/options.ini' )
```